# Forced download failing in middle

Tags: php

I made a script in PHP to download a file outside *public_html* (for security reasons) and for that I used the following script:

```
<?php
if(condition){
    set_time_limit(60 * 5);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 60 * 5);
    $path = "path/to/files";
    $fd = fopen($path, "rb");
    if ($fd) {
        $fsize = filesize($path);
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=OCTOPUS_3.1.zip");
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 1*(1024*1024));
            echo $buffer;
            ob_flush();
            flush();    //These two flush commands seem to have helped with performance
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Error opening file";
    }
    fclose($fd);
}
```

?>

But when I try to download the file it always stops in the middle of the download. I've already searched a lot of ways to deal with large files, but they are all already implemented in the code above.

Edit 1:
Just arrived home, where I have a faster internet connection and the download works fine.
But when I try to download with speeds around 100-200 kbps the download always stops in the middle.
Tried using:

```
header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked", true);
header("Content-Encoding: chunked", true);
header("Content-Type: application/zip", true);
header("Connection: keep-alive", true);
```

But it didn't work, even on fast connections,it says: *Failed. Network Problem*.

Also added:

```
set_time_limit(60 * 200);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60 * 200);
```

And it also doesn't work.

Comment: Stops in the middle of what? Perhaps your connection times out.

Comment: Stops in the middle of the download

Comment: Stop serving files through PHP, it simply sucks as a long running process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send a [chunked transfer response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Example:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(60 * 5);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60 * 5);

$fileName = __DIR__ . '/file.zip';
$baseName = basename($fileName);
$fileSize = filesize($fileName);
$file = fopen($fileName, 'r');

header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked", true);
header("Content-Encoding: chunked", true);
header("Content-Type: application/zip", true);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$baseName");
header("Connection: keep-alive", true);
header("Content-length: $fileSize");

while (($buffer = fgets($file, 4096)) !== false) {
    ob_start();
    echo sprintf("%x\r\n%s\r\n", strlen($buffer), $buffer);
    ob_end_flush();
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work, it says *Network failiure*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the php script times out. You should try setting an appropriate [time limit](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.set-time-limit.php) for yout script.

Although not guaranteed to work at all times: add the following at the top of your php file/function that does the download:

`set_time_limit(0)`

Then, if it works tune the time limit value to something that allows the download under slow connections too, like 600 (10 mins.)

Although this is not a silver bullet, users with very slow or unstable connections might still not be able to get the zip.

Comment: You could also try changing the setting `max_execution_time` in php.ini.